# $A^{k+1} = A$ for some $k\in \mathbb{N}$, then $A$ is diagonalisable

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

> Let $A^{k+1} = A$ for some $k\in \mathbb{N}$. Prove that $A$ is diagonalisable.

> Hint: $$(J_n(\lambda))^{k+1} = (\text{diag}_n(\lambda) + J_n(0))^{k+1}$$

So, I am not sure how to use the hint, and I'm just trying my own thing.

Since $A^{k+1} = A$, $A$ is a root of $p(x) = x(x^k-1)$. The minimal polynomial of $A$, say $m_A(x)$, divides $x(x^k-1)$. What's next? If I can show that $m_A(x)$ splits into distinct linear factors, I'll be done.

Let me know how I can proceed with this argument, and/or use the hint provided.

One thing that I found worth noticing is that $$\text{diag}_n(\lambda)^k  = \text{diag}_n(\lambda^k)$$Does this help?

Thanks!

Comment: $\mathrm{diag}_n(\lambda)$ and $J_n(0)$ commute. What are the only possible eigenvalues of $A$?

Comment: @strawberry-sunshine: Since $m_A(x)$ divides $p(x) = x(x^k - 1)$ and $p$ splits into distinct linear factors ($x = 0$ and the $k$ roots of unity), it implies that $m_A(x)$ also splits into distinct linear factors so $A$ is diagonalizable. The hint suggests to use the Jordan normal form instead, consider each block separately and deduce from the equality $A^{k+1} = A$ that $n = 1$ so that each block is $1 \times 1$.

Comment: Not necessarily true for positive characteristic.

Comment: @levap If I'm not wrong, $x^k - 1$ splits over $\mathbb{C}$, and not over $\mathbb{R}$ right? Does the result hold only for $A\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ then?

Comment: @strawberry-sunshine: I'm sorry, what I wrote is nonsense. If $A$ is a real matrix which satisfies your condition, it doesn't have to be diagonalizable over $\mathbb{R}$ (it will be diagonalizable over $\mathbb{R}$ if and only if the minimial polynomial of $A$ doesn't have any complex roots). I have deleted my (wrong) comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement is not true in general. E.g. $A=\pmatrix{0&1\\ 1&0}=A^3$ is not diagonalisable over $GF(2)$ and $A=\pmatrix{0&1&0\\ 0&0&1\\ 1&0&0}=A^4$ is not diagonalisable over $\mathbb R$. It is true, however, over $\mathbb C$ because the minimal polynomial of $A$, which divides $x^{k+1}-x$, is a product of distinct linear factors.

Alternatively, you may use the given hint. Suppose the contrary that $A$ is not diagonalisable over $\mathbb C$. Then via a similarity transform, we may assume that $A$ is in Jordan form. Therefore it contains a nontrivial Jordan block $J_n(\lambda)$ of some size $n$ such that $J_n(\lambda)^{k+1}=J_n(\lambda)$. But this implies that
$$
\sum_{r=0}^n\binom{n}{r}\lambda^{n-r}J_n(0)^r=\lambda I_n+J_n(0).
$$
By comparing the coefficients of $I_n$ and $J_n(0)$ on both sides, we get $\lambda^n=\lambda$ and $n\lambda^{n-1}=1$. Therefore $|\lambda|=1$ and  $n=1$, but this contradicts the assumption that $J_n(\lambda)$ is a nontrivial Jordan block. Hence $A$ must be diagonalisable.

Comment: What is $GF(2)$?

Comment: @strawberry-sunshine $GF(2)$ is the field with only two elements $0$ and $1$. We have $1+1=0$ on this field.